# NW.js stuck in loading state after submitting form in Express.js

Tags: forms, express, routes, loading, node-webkit

I'm looking to use nw.js to make an executable for my express.js app. It's been around 10 days since I've started fiddling around with node.js so please excuse my silly mistakes/phrasings.

The app works fine on browser. There's a form where I input a URL and submit which takes me to the '/getChapters' express route, some processing is done and then the view is updated with the result. But in nw.js, after I click the button, it just keeps loading and loading and loading. I removed all the processing parts and added a res.send("hi") just to see if it even reaches the route but no. Devtools only show client side stuff and there aren't even any errors. So I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Here's what I have:

package.json:

```
"main": "server.js",
```

index.pug:

```
form(action='/getChapter' method='POST')
          .input-group
            input.form-control(type='text' name='url' placeholder='Paste the URL of the manga' aria-describedby='basic-addon2')
            .input-group-append
              button.btn.btn-sample(type='submit' style='width:80px !important;')
```

server.js:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index.pug', { chap: [], res: 0 })
})

app.post('/getChapter', function (req, res) {
    console.log("hi") //can't even see if this shows 
    res.send("hi") //doesn't show up
});

server.listen(8081, function () {
    console.log("Example app listening at port 8081");
})

nw.Window.open('http://127.0.0.1:8081/', {}, function (win) { });
```

Node.js: 18.16.0

NW.js SDK: 0.50.0

Express.js: 4.18.2

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't have time to try this locally at the moment, but you can right-click > Inspect background to see the dev tools for node. There is also https://github.com/nwutils/nwdc which may help. Also when seeking help with NW.js, it helps to show your entire package.json

Comment: @Jaredcheeda Thanks for the reply. I tried Inspect background but nwjs just crashed. My pc is an old 32 bit windows 7 and I don't know if everything's fine in that... probably not. I'm unable to launch the app with nw . (which shouldn't be the case, right?) I can only open it by clicking on the nw.exe file. I tried it on a newer 64 bit windows 10 laptop and it works fine! No loading issues. So it's not the project that's the issue. I'll look more into it.

Answer (score 0):

This post was resolved by running on Windows 10 instead of Window 7.

Windows 7 support is dying off. For more information about what NW.js versions work with what OS's, check this post:

- https://dev.to/thejaredwilcurt/guide-to-nw-js-versions-5d38